# Can I change the value of a boolean when my while loop hits a certain condition to activate a second "outcome"? - Python beginner

Tags: python, python-3.x

I almost feel bad for asking a question already, given that I barely started my Python adventure.
However I can't seem to figure out the issue.

My code, me playing around with while, conditions, self assignment, etc., looks like this atm:

```
age = 14
drivers_license = False

while age <= 17 and drivers_license == drivers_license:
    print(f"You are {age} years old, so you are still too young to drive!")
    age += 1
    if age == 18:
        print(f"Now that you are {age}, you can get your drivers license!")
        drivers_license = True
    elif age >= 18 and drivers_license == True:
        print("You are allowed to drive now!")
```

'''
As you can see, I am trying to change drivers_license from False to True after the age reaches 18 and enable the last print.
I don't get errors but when I run the code I don't get the "You are allowed to drive now!" printed to the console.
'''

Comment: Your second condition is never satisfied because of the `age <= 17` condition in the while loop. After age becomes 18 and prints out the first message, it does not check the next block (`elif` aka else if is only checked if the original `if` is not met), and then exits the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I will see if I can fix it with that in mind.

Comment: Your conditional statement ```drivers_license == drivers_license``` is meaningless, since obviously driver_license is always equal yo drivers_license.

Comment: I would add that `drivers_license==True` is the worst thing my eyes have seen today. Why don't just `if drivers_license`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your code like this to find your solution!

```
age = 14
drivers_license = False

while age <= 18:
    if age == 18:
        print(f"Now that you are {age}, you can get your drivers license!")
        drivers_license = True
    else:
        print(f"You are {age} years old, so you are still too young to drive!")
    if drivers_license == True:
        print("You are allowed to drive now!")
    age += 1
```

Comment: I see! So having the second condition for my while loop was not a good idea. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
age = 14

while age <= 17:
    print(f"You are {age} years old, so you are still too young to drive!")
    age += 1
    if age == 18:
        print(f"Now that you are 18, you can get your drivers license!")
        print("You are allowed to drive now!")
        break #ends the while loop
```

Anything else is useless.

---

Notice this:

```
if drivers_license == drivers_license: #Always True
```

and this...

```
if drivers_license == True: # is equivalent to...
if drivers_license:
```

...and this:

```
if drivers_license == False: # is equivalent to...
if not drivers_license:
```